# IBM WAS Community Edition 8.5.5.0 java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version

Tags: web-applications, java-7, websphere-8

I am having a problem where WAS gives me an exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=test/xyz/abc/servlet/StartUp, offset=6
```

I have checked the compiled version of this file, the major version is 51. As per my research 51 is Java 7.

WAS has SDK 7 installed, the code is compiled and the ear is built using JDK 7. But i am still getting this error. Not able to see what could be the problem. Ideas?

Version of .class file:

```
Classfile /C:/Workspaces/TESTEAR/TEST_compiled_withIBMSDK7/TEST-web/WEB-INF/classes/test/xyz/abc/servlet/StartUp.class
  Last modified Sep 29, 2015; size 3475 bytes
  MD5 checksum cae118ff68e60ac948b1ea68f9faae1a
  Compiled from "StartUp.java"
public class test.xyz.abc.servlet.StartUp extends javax.servlet.GenericServlet
  SourceFile: "StartUp.java"
  minor version: 0
  major version: 51
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
```

I have installed IBM SDK 7 on top of IBM WAS 8.5.5.0 and installation looks to be successful.

IBM Installation details:

```
WVER0010I: Copyright (c) IBM Corporation 2002, 2012; All rights reserved.
WVER0012I: VersionInfo reporter version 1.15.1.48, dated 2/8/12

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IBM WebSphere Product Installation Status Report
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Report at date and time October 13, 2015 10:39:19 AM EDT

Installation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Product Directory        C:\IBM\WebsphereAS
Version Directory        C:\IBM\WebsphereAS\properties\version
DTD Directory            C:\IBM\WebsphereAS\properties\version\dtd
Log Directory            C:\ProgramData\IBM\Installation Manager\logs

Product List
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IBMJAVA7                 installed
BASE                     installed

Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                  IBM WebSphere SDK Java Technology Edition (Optional)
Version               7.0.9.10
ID                    IBMJAVA7
Build Level           cf071533.01
Build Date            8/20/15
Package               com.ibm.websphere.IBMJAVA.v70_7.0.9010.20150820_1342
Architecture          x86-64 (64 bit)
Installed Features    IBM WebSphere SDK for Java Technology Edition 7

Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                  IBM WebSphere Application Server
Version               8.5.5.0
ID                    BASE
Build Level           gm1319.01
Build Date            5/14/13
Package               com.ibm.websphere.DEVELOPERS.v85_8.5.5000.20130514_1044
Architecture          x86-64 (64 bit)
Installed Features    IBM 64-bit WebSphere SDK for Java
                      WebSphere Application Server Full Profile
                      EJBDeploy tool for pre-EJB 3.0 modules
                      Embeddable EJB container
                      Sample applications
                      Stand-alone thin clients and resource adapters

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this. After installing IBM SDK 7, i didn't update the ApplicationServer settings. We need to update the JDK 7 to be default on the application server. You can reach that by following the below path: Servers -> WebSphere application servers -> server1 (or the name of the server) -> Java SDKs. It will show up the image and you set the desired JDK as default.

[image]

Comment: how to add java sdk 7 ?

Comment: @ShaabanEbrahim I didnt try Java SDK 7, assuming you are talking about Java SDK which is not IBM's Java SDK.

Comment: no i meant IBM's java but it is okay i did it thank you :)